# Does GitHub support a feature like approval of the latest pulled code before pushing any commit?

Tags: git, deployment, release-management

I know we should do TDD to prevent this and I know release manager is the key responsible for something like this. But we are a small company at this moment and I have to do something urgently.

I need to create a deployment strategy for my company, shortly I must force the developers making a code review for the latest pushed commit before they send their code. My aim is to create a self-driven structure during deployment. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just get your developers to commit to a feature branch, and raise a pull request when they wish to merge to master.

Comment: what I meant was something like this https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/

Comment: Maybe you need [hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the remote repo? GitHub has information related to [how to use hooks](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) on their service. I wonder though if this is a lot of hassle for a small problem - do you think they will break your guidelines deliberately unless you stop them with a technical solution?